Compatibility of numbers when using Excel graphs and OpenPyXL
I'm updating an Excel spreadsheet with OpenPyXL. The lines in the code read:
s = workbook[aba].cell(n_rows,excel_REPLACE_col).value
cadena = str(s)
novus_value = NEW_VALUE[n_aba, n_rows-excel_satus_row]
snovus_value = str(novus_value)
workbook[aba].cell(n_rows,excel_REPLACE_col).value = cadena.replace(cadena,snovus_value)

where snovus is a string derived from a floating point number. This substitutes the numbers as required.
When I open the spreadsheet, everything looks fine and using formulas (e.g. average or sum) work fine.
However, the issue is that any graph takes all these values as zeroes.
Furthermore, and when I click on the cells and press Enter (without modifying anything at all), the graph now picks up the floating point number without problem.
My guess would be that OpenPyXL has added some character or changed some format but when I check the 'Alignment' or 'Number' tabs, everything looks as always.
